# powershell 4.0: Desired State Configuration requirements for remote clients

Tags: powershell, dsc

The whole DSC framework looks awesome, but I'm curious about the requirements of the remote machines. I create a custom MOF file and apply it to remove machines with Start-DscConfiguration (I'm simplifying the process a bit)- now do those remote machines also require the 4.0 management framework installed? When you hit remote machines with this are you just applying the settings via wsman or rpc\wmi commands or does the remote client have a special way of applying the settings? I guess my question is do both ends require the 4.0 framework or is this DSC just a simplified\abstracted way of managing windows boxes with get\set-WmiObject or Invoke-Command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Windows Management Framework 4.0 is a requirement on the client as well.

WMF 4.0 is included in Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1

Comment: And it can be installed on Windows 7,8,2008r2,2012.  Just don't install it on an Exchange 2013 server.

Comment: aw shucks.there docs that explain dsc on a protocol level- like what happens over the wire?